un form con 2 submit, al presionar enter como seleccionar cual se acciona
Verán, mi duda es que tengo la siguiente situación, en un formulario tengo 2 inputs de tipo submit aparte de varios de otros tipos, lo que sucede es que cuando estoy en uno y presiono "enter" me doy cuenta que se acciona "btn01". Mi pregunta aquí es si existe forma para que por defecto (presionar "enter") sea "btn02" el que se accione.
Nota: Por cuestiones de como esta organizada la pagina me es complicado simplemente colocar "btn02" antes de "btn01".
<?php
   if(isset($_POST["btn01"]))
   {...........}
   if(isset($_POST["btn02"]))
   {...........}
?>
<html>
   <form method="post">
      <input type="text">
      ..........
      <input name="btn01" id="btn01" type="submit">
      <input name="btn02" id="btn02" type="submit">
   </form>
</html>


Saludos. Solo debe tener input declarado type="submit" en cada form (y el grupo de elementos que lo conforman); el escenario que muestras en ambos existe tanto btn01 como btn02 sea cual sea se accione.

No, no existe forma de cambiar el botón default (lo que considero una carencia importante).
EL comportamiento declarado en la especificación del HTML establece que en el "envío implícito" (cuando se presiona enter) se activará el primer botón/input activo (no desabilitado) del tipo submit y esto no es posible cambiarlo
Cuando nos referimos al "primer botón/input" esto es el primer botón del árbol HTML (es decir en el código). Por lo que tú siempre puedes cambiar el orden visual empleando CSS. Lo cual sería una solución a tu problema; otra solución sería usando javascript.
Pero creo que lo más simple para tu caso es agregar otro botón invisible primero, este botón deberá tomar el mismo name que el botón que consideres defaut
<form method="post">
   <!-- Botón default-->
   <input name="btn02" type="submit" style="display:none">
   
   <input type="text">
      ..........
   <input name="btn01" id="btn01" type="submit">
   <input name="btn02" id="btn02" type="submit">
</form>


Yussef, ilumíneme. Porque sería "necesario" tener dos submits en un form?? Cual sería el beneficio de ello?? Los datos de tooooodo el formulario se van a enviar si o si, o hay algo que no veo?

@OCHOA El submit sigue siendo un input (una entrada de usuario que da información a ser procesada en el servidor). Podrías tener un formulario de pago y un botón "pagar en efectivo" y otro "pagar con tarjeta". Otro caso muy habitual es tener una tabla con datos y en una columna una botonera de acciones (eliminar, editar, ver) el típico crud; toda esa tabla puede estar en un único form  y cada botón indica la acción como la fila que aplica la acción

Otro ejemplo: En ASP Web Forms debes tener un solo form (ni más, ni menos), todo el framework se basa en la posibilidad de utilizar múltiples submit al mismo form

tienes razon, puedo meter un label con estilo asemejando el boton y simplemente le adjudico el accionar el input=submit con for="btn01", y el boton lo pongo hasta arriba y oculto.

ummmmm @Yussef, yo he hecho todo lo que usted ha ejemplificado con un único formulario. Pagar de diferentes maneras, un CRUD completo. Pero pueda ser que aun no vea lo necesario de esto. Gracias por la respuesta a mi comentario
